# Aliased registration for a COM component to allow concurrent calls

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, com, registry

There's a COM library I need to use that CANT be changed.
The Apartment State is STA and can't be switched to MTA without refactoring.

It's got two methods

- **Method One** is a short operation
- **Method Two** is a long running operation

I'd like to be able to make calls to **Method One** even if **Method Two** is in progress.
One approach I've considered is copying and altering the COM component's actual binary and registering it as a totally different COM component, then using an instance of this alias'd library to do the calls to **Method Two** so that the main instance is only responsible for calls to **Method One**.

I've tried just opening up the DLL in a hex editor and replacing the ProgID and ClsId, but that doesn't seem to be working.  The registry entries I'm aware of look right, but when I add a reference in visual studio in order to generate my interop assembly, the generated library still has the old ClsId and calls to **Method One** still block until **Method Two** completes.

Any ideas on how I can make this work?
Is this approach totally misguided or am I on the right track?

Comment: If the COM component requires you to use an STA then that means that you cannot call "method one" when "two" is executing.  Since the only way you could possibly do that is by using threads.  Which is explicitly not supported by the component.  Contact the owner or vendor of the component for advice.

Comment: Can't you simply create two threads, have both join STA, and have each create an instance of the component? What makes you think you need two distinct CLSIDs for that?

Comment: @HansPassant for the purposes of this question, just accept that the COM component can't be changed and that there's nothing to be done on that end.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I tried setting up two separate STA threads and it didn't seem to be working.  I'll revisit that approach -- maybe I messed up somewhere and wasn't doing it right after all.

Comment: For the purpose of an answer to this question, just accept that the COM component doesn't allow you to do this.  This limitation is as hard as a rock, you'll have to work with the original programmer to remove it.  Don't get your hopes up, you have a strong "no".  You might get a "yes", no other place to get it but from that programmer.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik you're absolutely right.  that worked as described in my answer.  Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating two STA threads to handle invocations to the component definitely allowed me to make concurrent calls.

The solution here actually was way simpler than the craziness I was talking about initially.  I had considered this solution before, but thought I'd tried it and it hadn't worked.  Something must have been wrong with my previous implementation.

Specifically, I've got two STA threads in which I'm instantiating my COM component, and then  I'm passing invocation requests to these threads via a blocking collection.  The calls specified in the request objects are made and the request objects are provided with responses which signals the calling thread that the call is complete.

@IgorTandetnik pointed me in this direction.